# How to validate an email "Entrycell" in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an email entrycell inside my tableview. I need to do behavior validation for that.I have done this for entry.
How can i do the same for entrycell?
My current code to an entry is given below.

/*

```
public class EmailValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{

protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
{
base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
}

void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
var email = e.NewTextValue;

var emailpattern = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
@"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";
var emailentry = sender as Entry;

if (Regex.IsMatch(email, emailpattern))
{

emailentry.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
}
else
{

emailentry.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
}
}

protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
{
base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
}
}
```

*/

Comment: Any help much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you replicate the same behavior and type it to <EntryCell> ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could custom viewcell with laber and entry,then add the behavior to the entry,or you could use CustomRender like this(a simple example for android, not sure if it meets your needs,ios is similar to thisto this):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryCell), typeof(MyEntryCellRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class MyEntryCellRenderer : EntryCellRenderer
   {
    string emailpattern = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
@"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";
    EditText _view;

    protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context) as EntryCellView;
        cell.EditText.AfterTextChanged += EditText_AfterTextChanged;
        return cell;
    }


    private void EditText_AfterTextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.AfterTextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(((EditText)sender).Text, emailpattern))
        {

            ((EditText)sender).SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        }
        else
        {

            ((EditText)sender).SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your Regular Expression on top of the declaration the Email property in your Model, than the property have value only if respect the regular expression condition.